# AWS CloudWatch log and disable log on server itself with springboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, server, logback, amazon-cloudwatch

In my springboot application, I configure to write logs to AWS CloudWatch, but the application also generates a log file log on the server itself in the folder /var/log/, now the log file is even larger than 19G

How can I disable the log in the server itself, and only write logs to CloudWatch?

The following is my current logback-spring.xml configuration. Any ideas will appreciate. Thanks in advance.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <configuration>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <springProperty scope="context" name="ACTIVE_PROFILE" source="spring.profiles.active" />

    <property name="clientPattern" value="payment" />  

    <logger name="org.springframework">

    <level value="INFO" />

    </logger>

    <logger name="com.payment">

    <level value="INFO" />

    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent">

    <level value="TRACE" />

    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received">

    <level value="TRACE" />

    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing">

    <level value="TRACE" />

    </logger>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">

    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [${HOSTNAME}:%thread] %-5level%replace([${clientPattern}] ){'\[\]\s',''}%logger{50}: %msg%n

    </pattern>

    </layout>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">

    <level>TRACE</level>

    </filter>

    </appender>

    <springProfile name="local,dev">

    <root level="INFO">

    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />

    </root>

    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="prod,uat">

    <timestamp key="date" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

    <appender name="AWS_SYSTEM_LOGS" class="com.payment.hybrid.log.CloudWatchLogsAppender">

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">

    <level>TRACE</level>

    </filter>

    <layout>

    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [${HOSTNAME}:%thread] %-5level%replace([${clientPattern}] ){'\[\]\s',''}%logger{50}:

    %msg%n

    </pattern>

    </layout>

    <logGroupName>${ACTIVE_PROFILE}-hybrid-batch</logGroupName>

    <logStreamName>HybridBatchLog-${date}</logStreamName>

    <logRegionName>app-northeast</logRegionName>

    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_AWS_SYSTEM_LOGS" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">

    <appender-ref ref="AWS_SYSTEM_LOGS" />

    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">

    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_AWS_SYSTEM_LOGS" />

    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />

    </root>

    </springProfile>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Not familiar with Springboot but as far as I know about Cloudwatch log, it requires a local file present on your machine. So you better of keep you current setting and set up a log rotation.

Comment: I removed  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">  &  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />

Answer (score 1):

The most likely fix is to remove this line:

```
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
```

I say "most likely" because this is just writing output to the console. Which means that there's something else that redirects the output to `/var/log/whatever`, probably in the startup script for your application.

It's also possible that the included default file, `org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml`, because this file defines a file appender. I don't know if the explicit `<root>` definition will completely override or simply update the included default, but unless you know you need the default I'd delete the `<include>` statement.

If you need to recover space from the existing logfile, you can truncate it:

```
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/WHATEVER
```

Deleting it is *not* the correct solution, because it *won't* actually be removed until the application explicitly closes it (which means restarting your server).

As one of the commenters suggested, you can use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to prevent the on-disk file from getting too large.

But *by far the most important thing you should do* is read [the Logback documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).